# C++ error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}’ and ‘int’)

Tags: c++

So I am writing this simple calculator in C++.
The error message says:

> main.cpp:38:6: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}’ and ‘int’)
> cin<<anotherQ;

And the code is:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int running = 0;
    while(running != 1) {
        float num1;
        float num2;
        char op;
        int anotherQ;
        cout<<"Enter 1 for '+', 2 for '-', 3 for '*', 4 for '/': ";
        cin>>op;
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"Enter a number: ";
        cin>>num1;
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"Enter another number: ";
        cin>>num2;
        cout<<"\n";
        if (op=='1') {
            cout<<"The answer is "<<num1 + num2<<endl;
        }
        else if(op == '2') {
            cout<<"The answer is "<<num1 - num2<<endl;
        }

        else if(op=='3') {
            cout<<"The answer is "<<num1 * num2<<endl;
        }
        else if(op=='4') {
            cout<<"The answer is "<<num1 / num2<<endl;
        }
        else {
            cout<<"Wrong operator"<<endl;
            running = 1;
        }
        cout<<"Do you want to do another sum 0 for Yes and 1 for No "<<endl;
        cin<<anotherQ;
        if (anotherQ == 0) {
            cout<<"Hmm.., Think u like maths well let's do another sum"<<endl;
        }
        else if (anotherQ == 1) {
            cout<<"Ok well byee!"<<endl;
            running = 1;
        }
        else {
            cout<<"crrrcrr u have given a wrong command byeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee! I was not desinged for handling such complex commands  as I was made by a 9 year old boy u will pay for it"<<endl;
            running = 1;            
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: include <iostream> ?

Comment: How do you compile the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
cin<<anotherQ;
```

in your code, which is incorrect.

```
cin >> anotherQ;
```

is the correct syntax.